# The problem of working with strings and numbers from a file displayed in a RichTextBox.C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

i'm newbie(and English sorry for that) in c# programming and have problem of working with string and numbers in richtextbox. I can't return numbers from strings to do some operation with digits and display result in new RichTextBox.Strings are getting from files.

**My Strings**(more than 2)

> Exam 1: 10 11 12 99 88 14;

> Exam 2: 60 41 72 93 55 44;

and "how do i need dislpay in new richtextbox"

> Exam 1: (Average);

> Exam 2: (Average);

Comment: You'll have to figure out how to **parse** and separate (**split**) your string into numbers. Then you'll have to figure out how to average them. Then you'll have to set the text box text to the value you get.

Comment: Perhaps with these, you can `string.split` on `':'` and then take second half of that array, and `string.split` on `' '`, to get an array of the numbers. Then convert each of those into integer (`int.Parse`).

Comment: @Ibrennan208 can i do "for(int i = 0; i < richTextBox1.Lines; i++){ string.split(":"); } buuut how get second haaalf

Comment: Slight different take, and in no way saying can't be done they way you're attempting but when doing processing on data, you are far better off working on the actual source of data rather than attempting to pull it all out the UI and parsing strings.  That content in your rich text box came from somewhere, so cache that "somewhere" as numbers to do your computations on

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/parse-strings-using-split

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code.

```
//the input string MUST look like: "Exam 1: 10 11 12 99 88 14;"
int sep_index = input.IndexOf(':');
int terminator_index = input.IndexOf(';');
int exam_number = int.Parse( input.Substring(5,sep_index -5));
var data = input.Substring(sep_index +1,terminator_index-sep_index-1).Trim().Split(' ')
             .Select(s=>int.Parse(s));
var average = data.Average();
```

You can start from there and make it more robust